# Using LINQ to combine similar rows of grouped data

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've got some data in a table that looks like so:

```
Recipe | Category | Email
```

What I'd like to do is pull this data back from the source and put it into something that looks like so:

```
public class RecipeItem
{
   public long Recipe { get; set; }
   public long Category { get; set; }
   public List<string> Names {get; set; }
}
```

Grouping by the Recipe and Category ids and putting all the emails that into the list.

So, what I've tried is to do something like this:

```
var recipeItems =
   from entry in list
   group entry by new { entry.Recipe, entry.Category}
   into aRecipe
   select new RecipeItem()
              {
                 Recipe = aRecipe.Key.Recipe,
                 Category = aRecipe.Key.Category,
                 // ? Not sure how to stick the list of names in here
              };
```

`list` is the data pulled back via entity framework.

But this isn't quite right - I think I'm close here (maybe).  What am I missing here on this?

---

**Follow-up:**

Thanks to Aducci for clearing this up.  The answer is that you can do this:

```
Names = aRecipe.Select(x => x.Name)
```

and this will add all those Names which are in each group into the `Names` collection for that group.  Pretty nifty.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/802337/231350 for some idea on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would modify your class to look like this

```
public class RecipeItem
{
   public long Recipe { get; set; }
   public long Category { get; set; }    
   public IEnumerable<string> Names {get; set; }      
}
```

And your link to entities query to:

```
var recipeItems =
   from entry in list
   group entry by new { entry.Recipe, entry.Category}
   into aRecipe
   select new RecipeItem()
              {
                 Recipe = aRecipe.Key.Recipe,
                 Category = aRecipe.Key.Category,
                 Names = aRecipe.Select(x => x.Name)
              };
```