# Conditional GroupBy() in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, matrix, guid

I'm working with a matrix filled with similarities between items. I save these as a list of objects in my database. The Similarity object looks like this:

```
public class Similarity
{
    public virtual Guid MatrixId { get; set; } //The id of the matrix the similarity is in
    public virtual Guid FirstIndex { get; set; } //The id of the item of the left side of the matrix
    public virtual Guid SecondIndex { get; set; } //The id of the item of the top side of the matrix
    public virtual double Similarity { get; set; } //The similarity
}
```

A user can review these items. I want to retrieve a list of items which are 'similar' to the items the user has reviewed. The problem is where I can't tell for sure whether the item's id is in the `FirstIndex` or the `SecondIndex`. I have written some code which does what I want, but I want to know if this is possible in 1 statement.

```
var itemsNotReviewed = Similarities.Where(x => !itemsReviewed.Contains(x.SecondIndex))
    .GroupBy(x => x.SecondIndex)
    .ToList();
itemsNotReviewed.AddRange(Similarities.Where(x => !itemsReviewed.Contains(x.FirstIndex))
     .GroupBy(x => x.FirstIndex)
     .ToList());
```

Where `itemsReviewed` is a list of guids of the items the user has reviewed and where `Similarities` is a list of all items which are similar to the items the user has reviewed. I retrieve that list with this function:

```
return (from Row in _context.SimilarityMatrix
        where itemIds.Contains(Row.FirstIndex) || itemIds.Contains(Row.SecondIndex)
        select Row)
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();
```

where `itemIds` is a list of guids of the items the user has reviewed.

Is there a way to group by either the first or second index based on the Where clause?

Please let me know if I should elaborate!

Comment: Hope [combine Where clause and group by in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/802337/3796048) might help you

Comment: @MohitShrivastava how do you determine which index is the key of the grouping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By my understanding, you have a list of `Similarity` which is guaranteed to contain items with either `FirstIndex` or `SecondIndex` contained in `itemsReviewed` list of `Guid`. And you need to take the elements (if any) with either index **not** contained in `itemsReviewed` (it could be only one of them due to the first constraint) and group by that index.

The straightforward LINQ translation of the above would be like this:

```
var itemsNotReviewed = Similarities
    .Where(item => !itemsReviewed.Contains(item.FirstIndex) || !itemsReviewed.Contains(item.SecondIndex))
    .GroupBy(item => !itemsReviewed.Contains(item.FirstIndex) ? item.FirstIndex : item.SecondIndex)
    .ToList();
```

But it contains duplicate `itemsReviewed.Contains` checks, which affect negatively the performance.

So a better variant would be introducing intermediate variable, and the easiest way to do that is query syntax and `let` clause:

```
var itemsNotReviewed =
    (from item in Similarities
     let index = !itemsReviewed.Contains(item.FirstIndex) ? 1 :
            !itemsReviewed.Contains(item.SecondIndex) ? 2 : 0
     where index != 0
     group item by index == 1 ? item.FirstIndex : item.SecondIndex)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I appreciate the input, but he gave me a solution which prevents the problem instead of solving it. I did some thinking on my own and altered it a little bit so it would work with my code.

Comment: No problem if that's the case - after all that's your issue :) My post is based on **I have written some code which does what I want** statement in your post. If that's wrong, please update the question and I'll delete the answer. I sure the code I posted does exactly what your code is doing, but in one step.

Comment: I just realized that you are correct, you gave me the correct answer based on my post, so you would deserve the bounty. Excuses!

Comment: As I said, no problem at all:) Glad it helped, also presenting exactly how to combine `Where` conditions with conditional `GroupBy`. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I would go for changing the way you source the original list:

```
_context.SimilarityMatrix.Where(Row => itemIds.Contains(Row.FirstIndex) || itemIds.Contains(Row.SecondIndex))
     .Select(r => new { r.MatrixId, r.FirstIndex, r.SecondIndex, r.Similarity, MatchingIndex = itemIds.Contains(r.FirstIndex) ? r.FirstIndex : r.SecondIndex })
     .Distinct()
     .ToList();
```

This way you only need to group by Matching Index.

```
var itemsNotReviewed = Similarities.
.GroupBy(x => x.MatchingIndex)
.ToList();
```

You may want to convert after the dynamic object to your Similarity class or just change the class to include the Matching Index.

You can convert them to your Similarity type by:

```
var itemsNotReviewed = Similarities.
.GroupBy(x => x.MatchingIndex)
.Select(g => new { g.Key, Values = g.Values.Select(d => new Similarity { MatrixId = d.MatrixId, FirstIndex = d.FirstIndex, SecondIndex = d.SecondIndex, Similarity = d.Similarity }).ToList() })
.ToList();
```

Comment: So `MatchingIndex` would be the id from the `itemIds` list?

Comment: Exactly, it will be the id On Item Ids

Comment: Alright thanks, but just keeping in mind that the function would have to return a list of `Similarity` objects, how would I convert these anonymous types to objects?

Comment: Edited answer on how to convert. Bear in mind that once grouped you will have multiple lists (one per group), but you get the idea

Comment: I might be stupid, but I don't fully understand where the `MatchingIndex` is used for. Since you convert the anonymous types to Similarity objects without using it

Comment: You use it in the grouping. The grouping return a list of Key, List<DinamycObjects>, so you need to transform for each key its list to the right object type. See updated code

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
(from x in Similarities
 let b2 = !itemsReviewed.Contains(x.SecondIndex)
 let b1 = !itemsReviewed.Contains(x.FirstIndex)
 where b1 || b2
 groupby b2 ? x.SecondIndex : x.FirstIndex into grp
 select grp)
.ToList()
```

The let statement introduces a new tempoary variable storing the boolean. You can of course inline the other function, too:

```
(from x in (from Row in _context.SimilarityMatrix
            where itemIds.Contains(Row.FirstIndex) || itemIds.Contains(Row.SecondIndex)
            select Row)
           .Distinct()
           .ToList()
 let b2 = !itemsReviewed.Contains(x.SecondIndex)
 let b1 = !itemsReviewed.Contains(x.FirstIndex)
 where b1 || b2
 groupby b2 ? x.SecondIndex : x.FirstIndex into group
 select group)
.ToList()
```

If you wanted to use non-LINQ syntax, you would probably need to introduce some anonymous types:

```
Similarities
.Select(s => new 
{
    b2 = !itemsReviewed.Contains(x.SecondIndex),
    b1 = !itemsReviewed.Contains(x.FirstIndex),
    s
})
.Where(a => a.b1 || a.b2)
.GroupBy(a => a.b2 ? a.s.SecondIndex : a.s.FirstIndex, a => a.x) //edit: to get same semantics, you of course also need the element selector
.ToList()
```

Comment: I have my `_context` in a repository, so I can't access that from my class. Also, `into group` causes me this error: `Invalid expression term 'group'`

Comment: Oh sorry, group is of course a used name, will fix.

Comment: What was your other problem? You can't access the _context from the outside?

Comment: Yes. I'm aware I don't need to create a repository for EF, but I like the abstraction since this is going to be implemented in another project.