# Linq select group by where syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I have these classes:

```
User {
    //identity user class
    public IList<Proyecto> Proyectos { get; set; }
    public bool IsImportant { get; set }
}

Proyecto
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   // more properties here    
}
```

What I am trying to do is to group by userId all the projects they have created and where `IsImportant` is true.

I have tried this

```
  var usuariosRobotVmInDb =await  _dbContext.Users.Include(p=>p.Proyectos)
            .groupby(u=>u.id)
            .Where(u => u.IsImportant== True)
            .Select(x=> new usuariosRobotViewModel
            {
                Id=x.Id,
                Name=x.Name,
                LastName=x.LastName,
                Phone=x.Phone,
                Email=x.Email,
                proyectosVms=x.Proyectos.Select(a=>new ProyectosVm {Id=a.Id,Date=a.Date})

            }).ToListAsync();
```

But it seems I can not use a groupBy and a where clause...How can I fix this? thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802329/how-to-combine-where-clause-and-group-by-in-linq

Comment: Why would the users table have multiple users with the same id?

Comment: sorry I do not get your question. A user have many projects, I want to list all projects from any user that is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with LINQ is that developers are still thinking in the SQL way and trying to convert it to LINQ Which sometimes doesn't work and sometimes is not optimal. In your case, you're using a navigation property when you're including the `Proyectos` object, and LINQ already knows the relationship between the `User` and `Proyectos` objects, so you don't need to group or do anything else:

```
var usuariosRobotVmInDb = await _dbContext.Users.Include(p => p.Proyectos)
        .Where(u => u.IsImportant) //Same as u.IsImportant == true
        .Select(x => new usuariosRobotViewModel {
            Id = x.Key,
            Nombre = x.Nombre,
            ...
        }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Apparently it's not, except for some more explanation about SQL vs. LINQ. I was typing my answer and only noticed yours after I saved.

Comment: I will leave it there just in case the explanation is useful to anybody, but +1 to yours.

Comment: I have a question...If I do not need to group by, how can I present the data into my view, grouped by user id?

Comment: That's a presentation matter. The data is already grouped by `User` (i.e. each `User` has a list of `Proyectos` objects. They way you present it is up to you. For example, you can use master/details view. If you have some issue with presentation, open a new question and provide your code.

Answer (score 2):

As you use navigation properties and the projects are already properties of your `User` class then you do not need to group by anything. Just retrieve the users where `Important` is true:

```
 var result = await _dbContext.Users.Include(p => p.Proyectos)
                              .Where(u => u.IsImportant);
```

*(And of course you can add the projection to the `usuariosRobotViewModel` object)*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What I would like to get is something like 
User1> //list of projects
User 2>project1,project45,project44

Comment: @deedee - you already have that in your object - just project it to the specific desired output