# GroupBy in EFCore using Include method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

EF Core 3.1

I have a LINQ expression that takes a userid and finds all logs associated with that user and then attempts to return an object that includes Name, TotalCount, and a List of Logs grouped by a Log property called Level. When I run the following code I get an error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Client side GroupBy is not supported.

```cs
var query = db.Users
              .Include("Logs")
              .Where(user => user.UserID == id)
              .Select(user => new 
                              { 
                                  User = user.Username, 
                                  Total = user.Logs.Count(), 
                                  Logs = user.Logs.GroupBy(log => log.Level) 
                              });
var result = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: FYI `user.Logs.ToList().GroupBy(log => log.Level)` doesn't work either

Comment: Put `AsEnumerable` before the first `.Select(user =>`. EF Core 3.1's support for `GroupBy` SQL Translation is sadly limited, but they are planning to improve it.

Comment: @NetMage thanks, I want to limit the amount of data being stored in memory and I believe AsEnumerable will execute the query so I was thinking of putting the groupby in a separate view instead

Comment: I think the problem is using the group by in the anonymous type. Did it work to put it in a view of Logs?

Comment: @sjb-sjb I gave up and wrote raw sql code instead lol

Comment: `AsEnumerable` splits the query into two halves and executes the second half on the client side. With your `Where`, only the one `UserID` would be stored in memory, with the included "Logs", so it doesn't pull any more than if the whole thing was done server side.

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802329/how-to-combine-where-clause-and-group-by-in-linq . Its not very intuitive but it worked. I voted to close